# How to use a macro parameter to call another macro in SAS

Tags: variables, macros, sas

I'm finding a lot of my macro jobs have a similar structure. To make my code tidier i'd like to make a generic macro where I have three inputs, the first date of when I run the job. The number of dates to run it for, and the name of the macro that I want to execute for these dates

Below is my code, it works if I hardcode the macro within the run_dates macro, but I can't call it using a macro variable passed as a parameter.
How can I use a macro variable passed as a parameter to call another macro?

I've added comments into the code where it doesn't work. i've simplified the outputs so they dont look interesting or logical but what i'm looking for is just to be able to use that macro variable.

```
%macro test_macro(dt);
%put macro date is &dt;
%mend test_macro;



%macro run_dates(dt_start, num, macro_name);

%put &macro_name;

%do i =0 %to &num ; 

    data _null_;
        call symput('querydate',"'" || put(intnx('month',&dt_start.d ,&i,'e'),date9.) || "'");
    run;

    %put prepaid daily for &querydate;

    /*this is where I want to call the macro*/
    %&macro_name(&querydate);

%end;

%mend run_dates;

/*now run the main macro*/
%run_dates('03jun2012', 10,'test_macro');
```

Comment: It's almost right, just remove the quotation marks from the name of the macro when you call `%rundates('03Jun2012', 10, test_macro)`. You're currently asking SAS to call `%'test_macro'` as macro baubles are all strings and the quotation marks get carried through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the quotes from macro_name

```
%run_dates('03jun2012', 10,test_macro);
```